# Why close method of java.lang.AutoCloseable throws Exception, but close method of java.io.Closeable throws IOException?

Tags: java, try-catch, try-with-resources

I was reading this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for `try-with-resources` and it says:

> The close method of the `Closeable` interface throws exceptions of type `IOException` while the close method of the `AutoCloseable` interface throws exceptions of type `Exception`.

But why? The close method of `AutoCloseable` could have also thrown `IOException` is there any example that support that close method of `AutoCloseable` must throw exceptions of type `Exception`

Comment: I think it's simply a bad decision on the language makers' part. It requires you to catch a generic Exception wherever you use try-with-resources.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `AutoClosable` interface is located in `java.lang` and is intended to be applied to any resource that needs to be closed 'automatically' ([try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)). The `AutoClosable` must not be an io releated resource. So the interface can not make any assumption of a concrete exception.

On the other hand `Closable` is located in `java.io` and extends `AutoClosable`, because a `Closable` is an `AutoClosable` for io resources. Therefore it declares that `IOException`s can be thrown on close.

For example... a `java.sql.Connection` is an `AutoClosable` because it's close method throws `SQLException` and a `SQLException` is not an `IOException`. Think about in memory DBs and it makes sense that closing an sql connection must not throw an `IOException`.

**EDIT**

> answered one more doubt i.e. why AutoClosable is kept under java.lang package. Thanks.

I think it is located in `java.lang` because [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) was introduced as a language feature in Java 1.7. Thus `java.lang`

Comment: answered one more doubt i.e. why `AutoClosable` is kept under `java.lang` package. Thanks.

Comment: @Vishrant I updated my answer... Late but I hope not too late :)

Comment: In fact, answered why `AutoCloseable` was created at all instead of just reusing `Closeable`.

Comment: Very good answer, René. Another way to put it is this: remember that `Closeable` existed before Java 1.7 and it's `close` method was already throwing `IOException`; I imagine that, when they introduced `AutoCloseable` and retrofited `Closeable` to extend it, they found that the `AutoCloseable.close` would necessarily have to throw a checked exception (inheritance/method overriding rules); `Exception` was the most sensible option in this case.

Comment: `The AutoClosable must not be an io releated resource.` This is incorrect and may be made correct by changing "must" to "may".

Answer (score 15):

Further to being able to throw some other types of exceptions than `IOException` one beautiful and common use case can be easily overseen:

One can override the interface to have no `throws` declaration at all, thus permitting `try` being written without explicit exception handling.

In our code we have an interface `Searcher` declared in the following way

```
public interface Searcher<V> extends AutoCloseable {

    Stream<V> search();

    @Override
    void close();
}
```

This permits the following use of `Searcher` instances:

```
try (Searcher<Datatype> dataTypeSearcher = new DataTypeSearcher(query)) {
    return dataTypeSearcher.search();
}
// without any catch statements
```

If no `throws` declaration was present on `AutoCloseable`, the above would be the only usage as it would not be possible to override the `AutoCloseable` interface throwing an exception not declared on the parent. The way it is currently done, both options are possible.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more than once.

Answer (score 10):

`Closeable` extends `AutoCloseable`, but there could be other particular interfaces that extend this interface. E.g.:

```
public interface MyCloseable extends AutoCloseable { 
    void close() throws RuntimeException; 
}
```

They wanted to have an interface that can be used in many cases, and this is why they decided to use `Exception` because it also works for other types of exceptions.