# AutoCloseable and throws exception

Tags: java, try-with-resources, method-invocation, autocloseable

The AutoCloseable has a method 'void close throws Exception'.
Some suggest to extend this interface and override the close method and remove the Exception. See for instance the below link.

But when i forget to put the statement in a try-with-resources statement is the close method than not called?

- In the try-with-resources the close is called
- In the stream api the close is called
- Automatically by java when for instance leaving the method in which the resource is created???

**Additional information**
I've searched on the internet and looked at the documentation. Both suggested to remove the throws Exception statement. But my reaction to this suggestion is that when in the future someone in our project implements the new interface (without exception) and forgets to put them in the try-with-resource that we have a resource leak. For our project it's not a huge issue because we're using SonarQube which will mention the resource leak

Example location:

- [Why close method of java.lang.AutoCloseable throws Exception, but close method of java.io.Closeable throws IOException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959779/why-close-method-of-java-lang-autocloseable-throws-exception-but-close-method-o)

Comment: *when i forget to put the statement in a try-with-resources statement is the close method than not called?* - this would be the same whether you are overriding `close` or not -

Comment: for your third bullet point. Java does nothing. You *have* to somehow invoke that `close` method. Even when it is only by placing it into a try-with-resources or using streams

Answer (score 1):

> The AutoCloseable has a method 'void close throws Exception'. Some suggest to extend this interface and override the close method and remove the Exception.

The link you posted isn't suggesting that as a general case, it's showing you why the `io` package has its own `Closeable` interface that only throws an `IOException` (because it doesn't need to throw a more general `Exception`.) This makes zero difference at runtime, it's purely in place so a compiler error is thrown if anything tries to throw something that's *not* an IOException while using the `io.Closeable` interface.

> But when i forget to put the statement in a try-with-resources statement is the close method than not called?

You seem to be implying a link here where there is none - the type of exception that an `AutoCloseable` might throw isn't really anything to do with when the resource it wraps is closed.

> In the try-with-resources the close is called

Yes, which is the whole point of the language feature.

> In the stream api the close is called

Not unless you wrap it in a try with resources block.

> Automatically by java when for instance leaving the method in which the resource is created???

Nope, if you forget to close a resource it'll just stay open.

(Only exception to this rule is if a resource closes itself in a finalizer, which executes just before it's garbage collected. This certainly isn't something to rely on though, it's just (sometimes) used as a fallback.)

Answer (score 0):

Try-with-resources automatically calls `close` when the resource goes out of scope (also: you can only declare an `AutoClosable` in try-with-resources). If you forget to put your resource in that language construct, you have to close it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The `AutoCloseable.close()` method is not a destructor (there are no destructors in Java) - it was specifically created for `try-with-resources` and therefore is not called if not used in that statement - see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html):

> The close() method of an AutoCloseable object is called automatically when exiting a try-with-resources block for which the object has been declared in the resource specification header. This construction ensures prompt release, avoiding resource exhaustion exceptions and errors that may otherwise occur.